# on input не учитывает пробел

Tags: jquery

Доброе время суток, есть input

```
<input type="text" name="filter_service" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_service; ?>" id="input-filter-service" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
```

Есть скрипт, который должен вызывать функцию, передавая в нее значение из инпута, задача вроде ясна и проста, но вот незадача все работает, но если вводить текст с пробелом то функция игнорирует все символы, что идут после пробела в инпуте!

```
$('#tab-service').on('input', 'input[name=\'filter_service\']', function() {
    var filter_name = $(this).val();
 
    if (filter_name) {
        $('#tab-service #service').load('index.php?route=auto/auto/Service&filter_name=' + filter_name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать **[encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)** или **[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)**

```js
$('#tab-service').on('input', 'input[name=\'filter_service\']', function() {
    var filter_name = $(this).val();
 
    if (filter_name) {
      console.log(encodeURI(filter_name));
        //$('#tab-service #service').load('index.php?route=auto/auto/Service&filter_name=' + filter_name);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tab-service">
    <input type="text" name="filter_service" value="hello world" placeholder=" " id="input-filter-service" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```